# Sound made by trapped water

Tags: pressure, acoustics, everyday-life, water

When I run water in my bathroom sink and then put the plug in whilst there is still some water left in the basin, there is a high pitch moaning or screeching noise made by my adding the plug. What causes this noise?

Comment: How is the drain vented? Does the drain connect to a stack with a vent that goes out through your roof? or is it vented with an _[air admittance valve](https://www.build.com/proflo-pf108202/s969302)_ under or on the countertop? If it's the latter, then the sound that you hear may be coming from the valve.

Answer (score 0):

We tracked a similar sound to a tiny leak in the flush/refill mechanism in the toilet.  Any brief alteration of water pressure anywhere in the bathroom could trigger the sound.  If you still get that sound when using a sink plug that you know for sure does not leak, try flushing the toilet to see if it stops the sound (even though the sound seems to be coming from the sink).

Comment: Thank you @S.McGrew   The sound in the sink eventually died away, so it must be something to do with trapped water I think.